# Defining treatments within a column in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I am trying to assign meaning to numeric values within a column. The numbers represent treatments that were carried out. I want to label treatments 1,2,3,4 as one thing and treatments 5,6,7,8,9 as another.

I then want to use this to fill in a geom_hist. Is there anyway to do this? I have tried a number of things but cant seem to figure it out.

UPDATE

I have now tried to assign colours to each treatment using scale_colour_manual which as far as I can tell should have worked but hasn't.

| Date | Plot | Treatment | B. perennis |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18/05/2022 | 1 | 1 | 170 |
| 18/05/2022 | 1 | 2 | 79 |
| 18/05/2022 | 1 | 3 | 380 |
| 18/05/2022 | 1 | 4 | 39 |
| 18/05/2022 | 1 | 5 | 405 |
| 18/05/2022 | 1 | 6 | 163 |
| 18/05/2022 | 1 | 7 | 17 |
| 18/05/2022 | 1 | 8 | 47 |
| 18/05/2022 | 1 | 9 | 193 |

```
    Cols <- c("1" = "purple",
          "2" = "Purple",
          "3"="purple",
          "4" = "purple",
          "5" = "red",
          "6" = "red",
          "7" = "red",
          "8" = "red",
          "9" = "red")

ggplot(data=Flower, aes(x = date, y = Bellis.perennis, fill = Treatment)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(Cols))+
  geom_col()+
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Blooms", title= "Bloom count B.Perennis")
```

Comment: Can you provide reproducible data and show us what you have tried? Something like `lbl <- ifelse(treatment < 5, "Label 1", "Label 2")`.

Comment: That worked great thank you I have sorted it now